# plot matrix with three colors

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to plot a data looks like :

```
NA B B A  B A NA B A NA
B  B B NA B B A  B A B
.
.
B  B B NA A A B  B A B

for each line
If A = red dot
if B = black dot
if NA = grey dot
```

Could somebody help me how I can do that

Comment: @SeñorO I coul not make it but I tried something like : plot(matrix , xlim=c(1,nrow), ylim=c(1,ncol), type="n") sapply(1:nrow, function(X) {points(1:ncol, rep(X, ncol), pch=ifelse(matrix[1,]=="NA", 19, 1)) })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but maybe something like this?

```
#some data
set.seed(42)
dat <- matrix(sample(c("A","B",NA), 25, TRUE), 5)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] NA   "B"  "B"  NA   NA  
# [2,] NA   NA   NA   NA   "A" 
# [3,] "A"  "A"  NA   "A"  NA  
# [4,] NA   "B"  "A"  "B"  NA  
# [5,] "B"  NA   "B"  "B"  "A" 

#reshape, so ggplot likes it
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(t(dat))
df$value <- as.character(df$value)

#to be able to plot NA values
df$value[is.na(df$value)] <- "NA"

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Var1, y=-Var2, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks=seq_len(max(df$Var1))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks=-seq_len(max(df$Var2)),
                     labels=seq_len(max(df$Var2))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("A"="red", "B"="black", "NA"="grey")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

If you really prefer dots, you can use `geom_point`.

**Edit:**

If your matrix has dimnames:

```
rownames(dat) <- letters[1:5]
colnames(dat) <- letters[6:10]
#    f   g   h   i   j  
# a NA  "B" "B" NA  NA 
# b NA  NA  NA  NA  "A"
# c "A" "A" NA  "A" NA 
# d NA  "B" "A" "B" NA 
# e "B" NA  "B" "B" "A"

#reshape, so ggplot likes it
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(t(dat))
df$value <- as.character(df$value)

#to be able to plot NA values
df$value[is.na(df$value)] <- "NA"

#get the order of rows as in print(dat)
df$Var1 <- factor(as.character(df$Var1), levels=colnames(dat), ordered=TRUE)
df$Var2 <- factor(as.character(df$Var2), levels=rev(rownames(dat)), ordered=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("A"="red", "B"="black", "NA"="grey")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: that is really great but I got this error: Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 12L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L,  : 
  max not meaningful for factors

Comment: I've added how to do it if your matrix has dimnames.

Answer (score 1):

This example is provided just to show in gory detail how it could be done.    This is far from the most compact code.

```
dmat[dmat=="A"]<-0
dmat[dmat=="B"]<-1
dmat[is.na(dmat)]<-2
mycolors<-c('red','black','grey')
# initial plot area
plot(c(1,nrow(dmat)),c(1,ncol(dmat)),t='n')

for (i in 1:nrow(dmat)){
   for(j in 1:ncol(dmat)) {
       points(i,j,col=mycolors[dmat[i,j]])
       }
   }
```

Comment: I do not know why I get this error: for (i in 1:nrow(dat)){
+    for(j in 1:ncol(dat) {
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"for (i in 1:nrow(dat)){
   for(j in 1:ncol(dat) {"
       points(i,j,col=mycolors[dat[i,j]])}}
Error: unexpected '}' in "       points(i,j,col=mycolors[dat[i,j]])}"

Comment: @MaryamSani  Sorry -- I left a parenthesis out in the "for(j..." line.  Fixed now.